# Difference between concat and merge in rxjs6

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have `lessons$` observable which is combined from `initialLessons$` and `searchLessons$` observables.

`initialLessons$` emits on the load of the page to get a list of lessons and when the user types in the search input `searchLessons$` emit to get the filtered results.

When I used `concat` to combine these observables, only the `initialLessons$` observable emits and it seems that it doesn't subscribe to `searchLessons$` at all. I replaced it with `merge` and it worked fine

I just need to know what's the explanation for this case!

```
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('searchInput') input: ElementRef;

  courseId: string = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

  course$: Observable<Course>;

  lessons$: Observable<Lesson[]>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.course$ = createHttpObservable(`/api/courses/${this.courseId}`);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const initialLessons$: Observable<Lesson[]> = this.loadLessons();

    const searchLessons$: Observable<Lesson[]> = fromEvent<any>(
      this.input.nativeElement,
      'keyup'
    ).pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      map(event => event.target.value),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(search => this.loadLessons(search))
    );

    this.lessons$ = merge(initialLessons$, searchLessons$);
  }

  loadLessons(search = ''): Observable<Lesson[]> {
    return createHttpObservable(`/api/lessons?courseId=${this.courseId}&pageSize=100&filter=${search}`
).pipe(map(res => res['payload']));
```

}
}

**Edit:**

This is createHttpObservable code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export const createHttpObservable = (url: string) => {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;

    fetch(url, { signal })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => observer.next(data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));

    return () => controller.abort();
  });
};
```

Comment: Its Because concat emits only after your observables completes... since FromEvent never completes for the above scenario it will not work...
Where merge emits all values even if its not complete

Comment: Show us the code of createHttpObservable.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added it to the question

Comment: Why don't you simply use the Angular HttpClient? It returns observables, which behave correctly (i.e. they complete). https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: I think that what I will do in the coming tasks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` will subscribe only to the next source Observable when the previous Observable completes.

And this is what doesn't happen in your code. An Observable created by `createHttpObservable` never completes. It only emits one `next()` but no `complete()`. So that's why you were experiencing what you described. `concat` never subscribed to `searchLessons$` because `initialLessons$` never completed.

Since you're already calling `.then(data => observer.next(data))` you can add there also `complete()` call.

```
.then(data => {
  observer.next(data);
  observer.complete();
})
```